# Python script stops after a few hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, save

I have a Python 3 script running what download images from the web, but it stops after a few hours and I can't figure out why.
I have URL's in a .csv file and it saves the images with the name what is provided in column 1 of the csv file.

I already tried to switch off the "print (url)", because I thought that this maybe took too much memory at a certain moment, but that didn't do the trick.

This is my script:

```py
import csv
import requests
print ('download.py map 3_new')

with open('3.csv') as csvfile:
    csvrows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        filename = row[0]
        url = row[1]
        #print (url)
        result = requests.get(url, stream = True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            open(filename,"wb").write(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that it's caused by not closing the files after saving images to your hard drive. Try to do it this way:

```
import csv
import requests
print ('download.py map 3_new')

with open('3.csv') as csvfile:
    csvrows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        filename = row[0]
        url = row[1]
        #print (url)
        result = requests.get(url, stream = True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            with open(filename,"wb") as f:
                f.write(image)
```

Comment: I'll try it, I have the command running now. Let's see what it does. Thanks for your answer in any case!

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick. I runned 6 python commands what all do the same action (the first on 1.csv the second on 2.csv ...... and so on). At the moment 4 of the 6 are still running, the other two closed without any reason. The URL's are good, because when I start over at the URL where it stopped, it downloads the image without any problem.

Comment: Somehow I don't believe that there was no reason for finishing prematurely ;) If there was no error, then maybe the script actually iterated through all urls from the csv file but for some reason status code was other than 200 and you are not checking that nor trying to repeat the download in case of a failure?

Comment: I'm also sure that there has to be a reason for finishing prematurely. I honestly don't believe that the script iterated through all of the URL's because it stops for example at 20% of the file, and if you start it again at the point where it stopped, it just continiue like how it should. It's true that I don't repeat the download in case of failure, but if I disconnect the computer from the internet for a minute or two and later connect it again, the script continiues again where it has ended.

Comment: Another thing what is strange, the 4 scripts that were still running shutted down at the same time. So maybe it's not the fault of the script, but of my computer/Python.

Comment: Can you check if streaming the data using `iter_content`, as recommended in the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) of `requests` helps (or results in raising some exception when the scripts finish prematurely)?

Comment: I've insert the ```iter_content```, and I'll let it run.

Comment: This night I let the script run with Sublime text and I got the following error:

```urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wwww.***.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /images/honda.JPG (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0367DFD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))```, you're right that it's probably caused by the internet connection.

Comment: Well, in any case it looks like you just need to add some error handling. If it's about retrying to establish the connection [urllib3.util.retry](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry) module may be helpful. If you experience other errors then handle them using `try`/`except` block in a way which will suite you best (wait / retry downloading / log files which were not downloaded / etc.)